# How do I properly close serial port connection and thread it runs in?

Tags: c#, serial-port

I have an serial port read running on a background thread, but everytime I try to close it, I get an exception. Usually an IO-exception.

It is as if the read continues on eventhough I close the thread.

This is my current code:

EDIT: I changed the code, removed the checks on threatstate.

```
public bool Connect(string portName)
    {
        try
        {
            sp = new SerialPort(portName, BaudRate);
            sp.Open();
            sp.DtrEnable = true;

             cf = SingletonFormProvider.GetInstance<ConnectionForm>(null);

            _continue = true;
            readThread = new Thread(Read);
            readThread.Start();

            return true;
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        { 
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);

            return false;
        }
    }

    public void Disconnect()
    {

        if (IsConnectionOpen)
        {
            _continue = false;
            readThread.Abort();

            while (readThread.ThreadState == ThreadState.AbortRequested)
            { }

            sp.Close();

            readThread.Join();
        }

    }

    private void Read()
    {

                while (_continue)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        string message = sp.ReadLine();
                        cf.WriteLog(message);
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {

                            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                            _continue = false;
                            readThread.Join();
                            sp.Close();

                    }

            }


    }
```

Comment: What does the exception error message say?

Comment: Well actually right now it returns to VS2010 without any error message at all...

Comment: Problem solved, then! :-) Next time it happens, check the exception out, it might point you to the right direction.

Comment: No... not problem solved... It crashes without errormessage, but I just changed it and removed the threadstate checks, and now i get an errormessage saying that "Thread was being aborted"

Comment: It is as if, it reached serial port read before _continue=false, but after thread has been aborted.

Answer (score 2):

You do know that what thread.Abort() does is throw a ThreadAbortException in the thread in question, right? In the thread you catch all exceptions that inherited from Exception. I believe that includes the abort exception. If you really must call Abort, you may want to close the serial port first since I believe that will cause any pending calls to return.

Comment: No I didn't. I removed the Abort, and while, but still I get an exception this time telling me. "The I/O operation has been abortedbecause of either a thread exit or an application request."

Comment: This reinforces my belief that it gets the thread.join while reading the serial port. That is before it can check that _continue is false but after the thread is joined.

Answer (score 0):

Join your read thread before you close the serial port:

```
public void Disconnect()
{

    if (IsConnectionOpen)
    {
        _continue = false;

        readThread.Join();
        sp.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: This made the application go busy. It didn't crash but Im not able to interact with it. Still think this is because an actual read is going on when it is stopped, I just dont know how to prevent it

Comment: How is your `_continue` declared? Did you declare it as `volatile`? This link should help you: [Create and Terminate Threads in C#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7a2f3ay4%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)